# How to submit a rails form in every change of a textfield

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I need to submit my form every time user change the fields in this form.

How can I do this using ajax?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add below code in your javascript:

```
$('#text_field_id').on('blur', function() {
    $('#form_id').submit();
});
```

Here, when you lose focus from your text field, your desired form(with id #form_id) will be automatically submitted.

Comment: But, if I do this way, it always call create action from controller.

Comment: In your form_for  / form_tag check to which action you are targeting. Based on that action (create/update) the form will be submitted. 
Above code is just responsible for submitting the form to the destined actions.

Answer (score 0):

In the end of "create" action, I rendered a view that changes attributes of the form, like this:

```
<% if (@register.id) %>
  $("form").attr("action", "/posts/<%=@registro.id%>");
  $("form").attr("method", "put");
<% end %>
```

Doing so, the form now acts like an "edit" form, not a "create" anymore.

My script looks like this:

```
$("form").keypress(function(){
   doSave();        
});

function doSave() {     
    $("form").submit();
 }
```